# Reading 16 bit unsigned raw image in c++

Tags: c++, image, fread

I am trying to read a 16 bits unsigned image (192*256) saved in raw format using the following lines of code:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("D:\\S1.raw", "r");
unsigned short bufferImage[1][192*256]; 
fread(&bufferImage[0][0], 256*192*sizeof(unsigned short),1, pFile);
```

However the values stored in the bufferImage do not correspond to the pixels values in the image.
I really appreciate your help with that.

Comment: I don't know anything about raw image formats, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) says there are many of them, and they "typically" contain a header with the image size, pixel layout etc. So are you sure this is just pixel data and nothing else? How large is the file in bytes? When you load into a hex editor, what do the first few bytes look like, etc.

Comment: How do you know they differ? Have you tried changing `"r"` to `"rb"` for `fopening()` binary files on Windows? Have you tried checking the return value from your `fopen()` and `fread()`?

Comment: Is your image greyscale? If colour, you need to read 3x as many bytes? How big is your file if you run `DIR D:\S1.raw` is it 129*256 bytes, or three time as much for RGB?

Comment: How about declaring an `unsigned short image[49152];` and reading into that to avoid too many pointers to pointers till you get the hang of it?

Comment: is it row major or column major?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I have tried all your suggestions and unfortunately it did not work. My image is in gray scale and doesn't contain any header.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I have tried all your suggestions and unfortunately it did not work. My image is in gray scale and doesn't contain any header. The raw data are dicom images imported in raw format using ImageJ @MarkSetchell

Comment: Dear Mark, I somehow came up with a solution to solve the problem. I realized that the line fread(&bufferImage[0][0], 256*192*sizeof(unsigned short),1, pFile); does not work correctly for pixel values above 255 even though the image is defined as 16 bits. So I had to normalize the pixel values between 0 to 255 using ImageJ, and then save it as .raw. Thanks for your time @MarkSetchell